# how to handle / in rest url in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, url

Hi I have The following service

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{userid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
  // implementation omitted...
}
```

input parameter userId = 123/4324/234
how to handle / in url

userId come from database
Please give an example

Comment: You cannot use `/` in the input parameter, since the controller will think this is a different resource. Instead, you need to escape the slashes as %2F.

Comment: Please give an example . what is %2F

Comment: /endpoint?userID=123%2F4324%2F234

Comment: As well as reading the linked duplicate question, you can read about [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to understand why that `%2F` is needed.

Comment: no I have Error 400